# How to impove the query with DISTINCT?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, distinct

Initially I had the following query:

```
SELECT 
  rm.`routeNumber`
FROM
  transactions tr 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN route_map rm 
    ON rm.`idStation` = tr.`idStation` 
    AND rm.`routeNumber` = CONCAT(
      tr.`routeNumber`,
      IF(
        tr.`letterOfRoute` REGEXP '[0-9]+' 
        OR tr.`letterOfRoute` IS NULL,
        '',
        tr.`letterOfRoute`
      )
    ) 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN station s 
    ON s.idStation = rm.`idStation` 
WHERE tr.`operationType` = 2 
  AND tr.`routeNumber` != 0 
  AND tr.idStation != 0 
  AND tr.`idFiles` IN 
  (SELECT 
    fin.`idFiles` 
  FROM
    files_in fin 
  WHERE fin.`idTerminal` LIKE 'V%') 
  AND rm.`routeNumber` IS NOT NULL 
ORDER BY rm.`routeNumber`
```

And this query worked properly (at least, with `limit 1000` restriction). But when I tried to change to output only non-repeating `rm.`routeNumber values:

```
SELECT 
  DISTINCT rm.`routeNumber`
FROM
  ...
```

This query started to work and it seemed to work infinitely. The bottleneck is `transaction` table, because this table contains a lot of data (255679420 rows), and there is a lack of indexes (e.g., there weren't indexes on any columns from query in this table, except for `idFiles`). I added index on `idStation` column and changed query the following way:

```
SELECT rm_dist.`routeNumber`
FROM
(SELECT 
   DISTINCT rm.`routeNumber`, rm.`idStation`
FROM
  route_map rm,
  station s
WHERE rm.`routeNumber` IS NOT NULL 
AND rm.`idStation` = s.idStation) rm_dist

WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT *
   FROM transactions tr
   WHERE tr.`operationType` = 2 
    AND tr.`routeNumber` != 0 
    AND tr.idStation != 0 
    AND tr.`idFiles` IN  (SELECT fin.`idFiles` FROM files_in fin WHERE fin.`idTerminal` LIKE 'V%') 
    AND tr.`idStation` = rm_dist.`idStation`
    AND rm_dist.`routeNumber` = CONCAT(
            tr.`routeNumber`, 
            IF(tr.`letterOfRoute` REGEXP '[0-9]+' OR tr.`letterOfRoute` IS NULL,
               '',
               tr.`letterOfRoute`)
        )
);
```

But nothing changed. Anyway the query seems to work infinitely, and it's useless to wait for the end of the query execution. Is there any other way to improve this query?

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` statements for all tables involved in your query.

Comment: Possible bug:  `letterOfRoute REGEXP '[0-9]+'` checks for "does it contain digit(s)".  If you wanted "is it only digits", you need `'^[0-9]+$'`

Answer (score 0):

Try using a inner join instead of a IN clause and avoid unuseful subselect

```
  SELECT 
     DISTINCT rm.`routeNumber`
  FROM
    route_map rm,
    station s
  WHERE rm.`routeNumber` IS NOT NULL 
  AND rm.`idStation` = s.idStation

  WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT *
     FROM transactions tr
     INNER JOIN (
        SELECT fin.`idFiles` FROM files_in fin WHERE fin.`idTerminal` LIKE 'V%'
     ) T on tr.`idFiles` = t.`idFiles`
     WHERE tr.`operationType` = 2 
      AND tr.`routeNumber` != 0 
      AND tr.idStation != 0 
      AND tr.`idStation` = rm.`idStation`
      AND rm.`routeNumber` = CONCAT(
              tr.`routeNumber`, 
              IF(tr.`letterOfRoute` REGEXP '[0-9]+' OR tr.`letterOfRoute` IS NULL,
                 '',
                 tr.`letterOfRoute`)
          )
  );
```